# Building ionic, cordova app I get an Error: Cannot find module 'sax'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am following instrucitons on how to start building Cordova apps for android using ionic. 
When i do "ionic platform add android" on the command line I get an error 
Error: Cannot find module 'sax'

Cannot find any solutions to that. Does anyone have an idea where this comes from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did originaly install it on powershell using npm install.

I didn't find any solutions so I just uninstalled ionic and cordova and reinstalled them both. That fixed the issue.

Comment: i.e. run "npm uninstall -g cordova ionic" and "npm install -g cordova ionic" See also https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1922

Answer (score 0):

try running `npm install` in your projects directory

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... in the error description I saw that it was refering "c:\users\my-user.cordova" folder... so I uninstalled cordova, manually erased that folder and installed cordova again, it works for me